# Обособление прилагательного запятыми

Tags: запятые

В каком контексте фраза, содержащая слово "неспособный", обособляется запятыми?

В моем наитии - любая фраза, если в ней "неспособный" можно заменить словосочетанием "который не способен".

"Ребенок, неспособный учиться."
Но
"Неспособный ходить инвалид."

Не понимаю, по какому принципу в первом случае остается обособление, если "ребенок" - подлежащее, "учиться" - сказуемое.

Потому что уточнение?
Или потому что я не прав, и запятых не должно быть ни в одном примере?

Answer (score 1):

(1) *Это ребенок, **неспособный учиться**.*

Это —  подлежащее, ребенок —  сказуемое. Неспособный учиться —  обособленный определительный оборот.

(2) ***Неспособный ходить инвалид**  смог справиться со своим заболеванием.*

Инвалид —  подлежащее, смог справиться —сказуемое, неспособный ходить —  необособленный определительный оборот.

В обоих случаях имеется распространенный  оборот: **прилагательное + инфинитив.**  *Неспособный (что делать?) учиться, ходить.* Это **словосочетание** на основе прилагательного, связь **примыкание**. Прилагательное — главное слово, инфинитив — зависимое слово.

В первом предложении определительный оборот находится **после** определяемого слова и **обособляется.** Во втором предложении оборот находится **в препозиции** и не обособляется.

Comment: О, сколько новых терминов - это выше школьного курса русского языка? Не помню таких правил при изучении в школе. В первом примере при отсутствии слова "Это" "ребенок" всё равно остается сказуемым? Я в этих случаях пытался как-то приткнуть причастия и деепричастия, но затем понял, что они там ни к месту. Так или иначе - спасибо за ответ!

Comment: А какие термины вас испугали? Препозиция? Это расположение перед определяемым словом  (долго же писать!).  Все остальные — средняя школа.  «Ребенок, неспособный учиться».  Это не предложение, а его часть. Ребенок (подл.) неспособен (сказ.) учиться. Вот это предложение.  Нужно использовать краткую форму. Хотите заняться грамматикой? Лучше начинать с основ, то есть понять, как строится предложение.

Comment: Предикативная основа: подлежащее (предмет)  + сказуемое (действие/состояние). Это (подлежащее), ребенок (сказуемое), неспособный учиться (обособленный оборот).  Ребенок, неспособный  учиться, становится проблемой для школы. И т.д. Все вопросы можно уточнить в школьном учебнике  Литневской (все необходимое и достаточное там есть). Уровень школьный, но хороший.  https://bookscafe.net/read/litnevskaya_elena-russkiy_yazyk_kratkiy_teoreticheskiy_kurs-5758.html#p23